# Nonnullhomotopic degree 0 map

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I would like an example of a map $f: M \to N$ between closed oriented connected $n$-manifolds (the smaller the $n$ the better!) such math $\operatorname{deg}(f) = 0$ but $f$ is not nullhomotopic.

Comment: $N$ cannot be a sphere (nor homotopic to one) by Hopf's theorem. So, look for tori.

Comment: For one where the source is a sphere take the map $S^3 \to S^1 \times S^2$ which is constant on the first factor and the Hopf map on the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S^1 \times S^1 \xrightarrow{\pi_1} S^1 \cong S^1 \times \{1\} \hookrightarrow S^1 \times S^1$$